# Calculating the score of fields using MAX and MIN

Tags: mysql, max, min

The query's objective in brief is to list all the posts according to its score, which is calculated according to a calculate scores of date, views, and rating

```
 SELECT
          p.id
         , p.date
         , p.title
         , r.module
         , r.module_id
         , IFNULL(v.total_views,0)  AS views
         , r.total_rating           AS rating

     #the following formula calculates the Score 10*(MAX(points)-(points))/(MAX(points)-MIN(points))

    , round((round(10-(((PD.MaxDate-p.date)/(PD.MaxDate-PD.MinDate))*10), 3) + round(10-(((MAX(v.total_views)-v.total_views)/(MAX(v.total_views)-MIN(v.total_views)))*10), 3) + round(10-(((MAX(r.total_rating)-r.total_rating)/(MAX(r.total_rating)-MIN(r.total_rating)))*10), 3))/3, 3) AS Score


  FROM  posts p

  LEFT  JOIN ( SELECT ra.module_id
              , ra.module   AS module
              , SUM(ra.ilike)    AS total_rating
           FROM rates ra
          WHERE ra.module = 'posts'
          GROUP
             BY ra.module_id
       ) r ON r.module_id = p.id

  LEFT  JOIN ( SELECT pv.post_id
              , SUM(1)    AS total_views
           FROM posts_views pv
          GROUP
             BY pv.post_id
       ) v ON v.post_id = p.id

   JOIN (SELECT MIN(date) AS MinDate, MAX(date) AS MaxDate FROM posts) PD


    ORDER BY Score DESC
```

**The problem with the query is that it only give 1 row result instead of showing all of the posts.**

I think the problem is with using MAX() and MIN() without separating it from the LEFT JOIN query used to get the SUM() of the Rating and the Views.

THE MCVE
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70d1ec/1

Comment: You've already identified the problem. What are you asking for?

Comment: The problem with the query is that it only give 1 row result instead of showing all of the posts. I need the fix the query so that it shows all the posts not only 1 row.

Comment: Yes, and as you said, the problem is that you are using MAX and MIN which will aggregate your result set into one row. So, you need to move your MAX and MIN calculation into a sub query to preserve the full result set in the outer query.

Comment: I am unable to do it.

Comment: Try to add something like `JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t.total) AS max_views, MIN(t.total) AS min_views FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM posts_views GROUP BY post_id ) t ) mv` to your query. That will give you mv.max_views and mv.min_views that you can use instead of MAX() and MIN()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to add the following lines thanks for **Ivar Bonsaksen**:

```
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t.total) AS max_views, MIN(t.total) AS min_views FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM posts_views GROUP BY post_id ) t ) mv
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t.total) AS max_rates, MIN(t.total) AS min_rates FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM rates GROUP BY module_id ) t ) mr
```